# Most recent status for each order and when was it set to that value

Tags: sql, window-functions

I'm attempting to find the most recent status for each order and when it was set to that value. I tried the query below but what happens is [this](https://imgur.com/a/XmGgv3y). I just want it show the most recent status not all of them. Thank you so much!

```
select order_id, updated_at, order_status
from (select order_id, 
        updated_at, 
        order_status,
        row_number() over(partition by order_id, order_status order by updated_at desc)
          as rn
     from fishtownanalytics.order_status_history) as x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Your link is dead. But anyway: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep. Make your post self-contained.  Please read & act on [mcve]. If you do add a link, use edit functions to insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove status from partition it will work

```
select order_id, updated_at, order_status
from (select order_id, 
        updated_at, 
        order_status,
        row_number() over(partition by order_id  order by updated_at desc)
          as rn
     from fishtownanalytics.order_status_history) as x
where rn = 1
```